# host -t MX pro.lan -> pro.lan has no MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record

Setting up some service on my server. DNS/DHCP/Gateway ok for my own local network.
Planning to host a web mail server (working on local for users for now)

I added in my dns A and MX record (rDNS also) my mail server

```
smtp.pro.lan.   IN  A   192.168.84.30
smtp.pro.lan.   IN  MX  10 192.168.84.30
```

But when I try

```
host -t MX pro.lan
pro.lan has no MX record
```

I can't find where the problem come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the domain apex for the MX. Think of an MX record logically as "*mail for `pro.lan` should go to this server*".

So, for example:

```
smtp.pro.lan. IN A  192.168.84.30
pro.lan.      IN MX smtp.pro.lan.
```